# Custom UISearchbar searchresults tableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uisearchbar

I have a custom layout tableviewcell for showing my normal tableview but when I search the tableview with the UIsearchbar the search results ignore the custom layout e.g. cellbackground.

Where can I layout custom cells for searchresults?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use a UISearchDisplayController, you should set your controller to be the data source for the results table. Then you return the custom cells in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (check the table view provided by the the first argument).

Comment: Yeah, I did use UISearchDisplayController, I just called it incorrectly. Thanks for the reminder